# Weird \hspace with innerleftmargin of mdframed

Tags: spacing, indentation, mdframed

I'm now using `mdframed`, and I found that the indentation within `mdframed` environment is weird. For example, when outside that environment, if we use `\hspace*{2em}` in the second line, the number `1` in the second line is almost directly under the number 5 and 6 in the first line. However, if these two lines are placed in a `mdframed`, then this time the 1 is right under 5. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent = 0pt
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{everyline=true,splittopskip=15pt,innerleftmargin=2em,linewidth=1.3pt}
\begin{document}
12345678
\par \hspace*{2em} 12345678
\begin{mdframed}
12345678
\par\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 12345678
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unrelated to `mdframed` You see the same with

```
12345678
\par \hspace*{2em} 12345678
\par \hspace*{2em}12345678
```

the middle line has an additional word space as well as the `\hspace`. Your mdframed example did not have the extra space.

Comment: I see. Actually, I was testing with Chinese, but when I convert it to a pure LaTeX MWE, I mistakenly use a non-sense example. I'm still testing. By the way, I'm now encountering a new problem: when I use the user command `\newcommand{\myindent}{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0}`, then use `12345678\par\myindent 12345678`, the second line wouldn't appear. Can you help me figure out why?

Comment: I post a new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376718/section-title-shifting-in-mdframed-with-hangindent-used).

Comment: @Eric you need a space after `0` your definition comes to `\hangindent=2em\hangafter=012345678` so sets a very big hangafter you want `\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 12345678` to set it to 0 then typeset 123