# Section title shifting in mdframed with \hangindent used

Tags: indentation, mdframed

I have a code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent = 0pt
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{everyline=true,splittopskip=15pt,innerleftmargin=2em,linewidth=1.3pt}
\begin{document}

\section{Apple}
Some words..
\par\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 Test
\begin{center}
center
\end{center}
\section{Bird}

\begin{mdframed}
\section{Apple}
Some words..
\par\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 Test
\begin{center}
center
\end{center}
\section{Bird}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Q1. Why does the section shift in the `mdframed` environment? (See the section 4.)

Q2. If I either remove the `center` environment or the `\hangindent` line, the typesetting in the `mdframed` is same as outside it. Why?

Comment: I wouldn't try to correct/debug mdframed. Use tcolorbox instead. E.g. `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}` and then `\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,sharp corners,enhanced jigsaw,opacityback=0]`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So you guess this is a bug of `mdframed`?

Comment: I didn't try to find out. Imho tcolorbox is so much better than mdframed that there is no real use nowadays for the later and I never use it in new documents.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see! I just tried, and it looks pretty good. One last question, how can I enclose the box whenever the box crossing pages and adjusting the inner left margin to 2em?

Comment: tcolorbox has a very good documention with lots of examples. So see section "options keys - geometry" and "library breakable".